# "Aikido is first and foremost BUDO"

Tags: aikido, history, japanese

The above sentence has been attributed to O'Sensei and I'd like to use it as a motto for my dojo's website.

Problem: I can't find a reliable source about when/where he said this. Or a proper Japanese version of the original sentence, either.

I have tried to cobble together a [Japanese version first](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/how-to-write-aikido-wa-ichiban-budo-desu), hoping to be able to google for it and see if I can get something from Japanese sites... no success so far.

Can someone please point me to a credible source, and possibly to the correct japanese quote used by Ueshiba?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a quote from Kisshomaru Ueshiba in "The Spirit of Aikido" (合氣道のこころ). I don't have the English version to compare, but in the Japanese version it's the first line of the first chapter:

合氣道は、いうまでもなく本質的に武道である。

Kisshomaru expressed the same sentiment many times - his father may have as well, but I don't recall off hand. Morihei more often talked about things like "true" Budo.

Comment: Does anyone have the direct translation of that Japanese quote? Would be good to edit that into this accepted answer.

Comment: It's not something you can directly translate one way. Japanese is ideogrammatic - Literally it would be something like "Harmony Energy Way (Subject), said but wasn't original nature is warrior way was to be." A less literal way to translate is "It goes without saying The Way of Peace is essentially the way of the Warrior."

Answer (score 6):

I haven't been able to find a reference to that direct quote. There are a number of things that mean the same thing. O'Sensei appears to have spoken often about being on a quest to find the perfect Budo, and that Aikido (or Aiki Budo) is the result of that search.

The closest quote I've found is:

> "On reflection, Aikido can be seen as the root source of Japanese Budo." [O'Sensei Memoirs, pg 18](http://www.cityaikido.com/osensei-memoirs.pdf)

I found several quotes which speak to that idea but are not as short.

> “True budo is a work of love...Aikido is the realization of love.” [ref](http://www.losangelesaikikai.org/aikido/teachings/)
>
> "“Understand Aikido first as budo and then as the way of service to construct the World Family." [ref](http://www.losangelesaikikai.org/aikido/teachings/)

Here's a Q/A session with O'Sensei about True Budo

> First I learned Tenshinyo-ryu Jujitsu from Tozawa Tokusaburo Sensei, then Kito-ryu, Yagyu Ryu, Aioi-ryu, Shinkage-ryu, all of them Jujitsu forms. However, I thought there might be a true form of Budo elsewhere. I tried Hozoin-ryu Sojitsu and Kendo. But all of these arts are concerned with one-to-one combat forms and they could not satisfy me. So I visited many parts of the country seeking the Way and training. . . but all in vain.
>
> A: Is that the ascetic training of the warrior?
>
> O Sensei: Yes, the search for the true Budo. When I used to go to other schools I would never challenge the Sensei of the dojo. An individual in charge of a dojo is burdened with many things, so it is very hard for him to display his true ability. I would pay him the proper respects and learn from him. If I judged myself superior, I would again pay him my respects and return home.
>
> B: When did Aikido come into being?
>
> O Sensei: As I said before, I went to many places seeking the true Budo... Then, when I was about 30 years old, I settled in Hokkaido. On one occasion, while staying at Hisada Inn in Engaru, Kitami Province, I met a certain Takeda Sokaku Sensei of the Aizu clan. He taught Daito-ryu Jujitsu. During the 30 days in which I learned from him I felt something like an inspiration. Later, I invited this teacher to my home and together with 15 or 16 of my employees became a student seeking the essence of Budo. [ref](http://www.aikiweb.com/forums/showthread.php?p=268150)