# Translation for "Those who are possessed by nothing possess everything."

Tags: aikido

I am looking for the original Japanese phrase for the above quote by Ueshiba Morihei 植芝 盛平, and haven't been able to find it. It is in his book "The Art of Peace", but I haven't got a Japanese version. Could somebody please give me the correct translation or point me to a reliable source for the right Japanese wording? Thank you.

Comment: [japanese.se](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/) might help as well.

Comment: Not so much: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11494/translation-for-those-who-are-possessed-by-nothing-possess-everything

Comment: The OP failed to mention that this question was [previously asked on japanese.se](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11491/please-help-me-find-a-translation), where it was closed as off-topic.  I didn't think it was fit to migrate here, but one user [did have luck re-asking a similar question from japanese.se on MA](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/aikido-is-first-and-foremost-budo/1632), so I pointed that out in a comment.

Comment: Does anybody have the title of the book from which the translation was drawn? Japanese titles tend to be a little less concise...

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that there is no original Japanese version of *The Art of Peace*, since [John Stevens' book is a collection of Ueshiba Morihei's quotes from various sources](http://www.aikiweb.com/forums/showthread.php?t=13217).

At best, I think you could try to find Japanese versions of other books by him, but I haven't been able to find any resources that suggest they contain the original Japanese version of the quote.